# AutoDownload a file with PHP

Tags: php

I'm doing a little script that convert a csv to json with php.
I would like that, when you upload the file and the conversion is done, the converted file is automatically downloaded

```
exec(/*some stuff*/); // i call the script that convert the csv into json, i get my converted file path back
chmod($newFilePath, 0777); // i give all access to the new file
startDownload($newFilePath); // i ask the autoDownload
```

And here is the download function

```
function startDownload($path){
    if (file_exists($path)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($path));
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
        readfile($path);
        exit();
    }
}
```

If I echo `readfile($path);` or `filesize($path)` I got the file content (which is exactly want i want) and the good informations, and I'm sure the path is correct. But when i execute the script nothing happens.

I'm probably missing something dumb ^^

How can I make the user download this json file?

I tried to make a link and he do the same, is this a problem of access or something like that?

**EDIT :**

I tester this script in Local, it works perfectly, so the problem is from the permissions or something like that. I'm really bad with this kind of stuff, so if you have some idea that could help ^^

Thx for the help!

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: The server Hide the errors, so I tested in local, and it works perfectly.

So it's probably a problem with the permissions or stuff like that, but I'm bad with this stuff. Do you have some idea ? ^^

Comment: The server shouldn't hide errors if you include the code I shared above unless something else overrides error display. If it worked perfectly locally you do not have a missing semi-colon as pointed out below.

Comment: @JayBlanchard $path is the path of the json file created after the conversion. Also, i think the server overrides the php errors, it's a prod/dev server so this kind of error message are probably hided  :s

Comment: Try to run readfile($newFilePath); instead of download in the first part to check if the file gets read OK

Comment: Without being able to see the errors on prod we'll only be guessing. Can you check the error log?

Comment: If you think it is a permissions problems, here are some tips. Use `ls -l` to view the permission of folders/file, web-server usually runs as www-data (user and group) so thats who needs the permission. `chmod` and `chown` are useful for adjusting permission. Check out man pages or google for more info.

Comment: @dan08 thx for the tip 

Ok it's fixed, it was a problem in the folder that didn't had the good permission. Thx for help and sorry for the waste of time ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing semicolon after `exec` :

```
exec(); // i call the script that convert the csv into json, i get my converted file path back
chmod($newFilePath, 0777); // i give all access to the new file
startDownload($newFilePath); // i ask the autoDownload
```

I woul'd check if chmod has really changed the path permission:

```
if(chmod($newFilePath, 0777)){
    startDownload($newFilePath); 
}else{
    die('Permission denied');
}
```

Comment: Yes sry, i rewrited this part of the code on stackOverflow to make it more clear, but there is all the semicolon in the real script ^^

Comment: maybe a little check on `chmod` permission or maybe your `exec` content?

Comment: Ok it's fixed, it was a problem in the folder that didn't had the good permission. Thx for help and sorry for the waste of time ^^